# Closing of TCP socket - What is different when connection is closed by debugger

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I create a socket connection to a PLC:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(plcAddress, PORT);
m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
m_socket.Connect(endPoint);

m_stream = new NetworkStream(m_socket);
m_writer = new StreamWriter(m_stream);
m_reader = new StreamReader(m_stream);
```

When I close my program or the user clicks on logout then I call this code:

```
if (m_reader != null) m_reader.Close();
if (m_writer != null) m_writer.Close();
if (m_stream != null) m_stream.Close();
if (m_socket != null)
{
    m_socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    m_socket.Disconnect(false);
    m_socket.Close();
    m_socket.Dispose();
    m_socket = null;
}
```

But the PLC does not realize that the connection was closed. I cannot change any code on the PLC.

But when I stop the VisualStudio debugger (Shift+F5) while the connection is active, it is closed correctly. What is VisualStudio doing differently?

**Edit**:

These 2 lines are captured by wireshark additionally when I stop the program by Shift+F5

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I have a thread that reads data:

```
while (m_runListener)
{
    int cnt = m_reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
    if (cnt > 0)
    {
        // handle data
    }
}
```

When I close the program, I cannot stop the thread without calling `Thread.Abort();`
If I delete the blocking call `m_reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);` just for testing, the disconnect works.

Comment: What is the OS you use?

Comment: Read is not documented as a blocking function. There is in fact a ReadBlock() version. Is it activated over and over because you didn't delete m_runListener?

Comment: @o_weisman: No, I set m_runListener to false. And I'm definitely sure that `Read` is blocking (I set a breakpoint behind the read function and it only gets hit when really data is read)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx and I quote: "This method returns after either the number of characters specified by the count parameter are read, or the end of the file is reached. ReadBlock is a blocking version of Read."

Comment: By the way, Microsoft documentation claims that you should Dispose of your NetworkStream object instead of calling Close().

Comment: I think it depends on the type of stream if the Read() function is blocking or not. The MSDN quote speaks about file. A network stream does not have an end as far as I know.

Comment: MSDN states for NetworkStream.Read() that: "If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0"

Comment: Note that when you read `0` bytes from a TCP socket, you're supposed to end the connection - that's the "disconnect" signal. You shouldn't call `Read` again after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem here: 
http://sysperf.yingyuhsieh.com/2007/08/force-tcp-closed-by-sending-rst-c.html

Normally the TCP connection is closed as follows:

1. The client sends `FIN` to the server and the server responds with `ACK`
2. The server sends `FIN` to the client and the client responds with `ACK`

In my case the second step was missing.

I needed to force that a `RST` packet was sent. This can be done by the following code:

```
m_socket.Send(new byte[1]);
m_socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue recently and I also found that debugging through Visual Studio made the issue go away too. I believe this is due to the extra time it takes for the debugger in Visual Studio to do things, coupled with break points that obviously stop code execution that you may have in your closing code.

My rather nasty work around was to put `Thread.Sleep(xxxx)` calls between some of the closing code. I had one after the `Shutdown` and `Disconnect` calls to allow these processes to finish. I tried different values, but I settled with 100ms as that made sure the issue never occurred again.

Obviously a better way would be to see if you could put those calls into an asynchronous method and only call the next when the first is done, but I didn't bother due to the small size of the project and little use it will get.

However, I could be completely wrong and this isn't the issue you are having, it just sounds very similar to the issue I had a few weeks ago.

Comment: I added `Thread.Sleep` after each of my statements but no change

Comment: @FlatEric Sorry to hear that, obviously there is more to your issue that mine.